# Does the quotient of an A-module by a multiplicative subset of A act like a module on A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

(Lang, "Algebraic Number Theory")

> Let $K$ be the quotient field of $A$.

A **quotient field** is constructed by defining an equivalence relation on $R \times R^*$ where $(n, d) \sim (m, b)$ when $nb = md$ (an equivalence class of pairs of elements whose product is the same). The quotient field is the ring $R \times R^*$ factored by $\sim$, that is, the ring whose elements are the **equivalence classes** under $\sim$.

> Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$. $S^{-1}$A is the quotient ring formed specifically with the elements of $S$. $A$ has a canonical inclusion in $S^{-1}A$.

Is it $f: A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ where $x \mapsto (x, 1)$?

> If $M$ is an $A$-module contained in some field $L$, containing $K$, $S^{-1}M$ is all elements $\frac{v}{s}$, $v \in M$, $s \in S$.

That is, $M$ is like a normal module, except its law of composition is only defined for element of $S$. However, I don't know if the definition of $S^{-1}A$ as a quotient ring, applies for $S^{-1}M$. This would mean an equivalence relation $M \times S$ where $(m, s) \sim (n, t)$ when $tm = sn$.

$M$ is contained in $L$, and $L$ also contains $K$, the quotient field of $A$.

> Then $S^{-1}M$ is an $S^{-1}A$-module.

This means that it respects the module structure when $S^{-1}A$ acts as its underlying ring.

For example, presumably, $(a, s) · ((m, t) + (n, r)) = ((a, s) · (m, t)) + ((a, s) · (n, r))$, and so on.

The relationship between $M$ and $A$ is not clear to me. Assuming their elements do not significantly overlap, is the simple point here that if $M$ is an $A$-module, then you can basically "quotient" both sides of the relationship, and it still acts a module?

What about just $S^{-1}M$, does it also act as an $A$-module, or does this only act as an $S^{-1}A$-module?

Comment: Note that even if $A$ is an integral domain, some modules over $A$ might not be $A$-torsion free.  So, in defining $S^{-1} M$, even in the case of $A$ being an integral domain, in general you need to define $(m, s) \sim (n, t)$ if there exists $u \in S$ such that $u (tm - sn) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, but in the case $M$ is contained in an extension field of the quotient field of $A$, then the definition you gave of $S^{-1} M$ will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it $f: A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ where $x \mapsto (x, 1)$?

Yes.

> That is, $M$ is like a normal module, except its law of composition is only defined for element of $S$.

Did not get that, sorry.

> However, I don't know if the definition of $S^{-1}A$ as a quotient ring, applies for $S^{-1}M$. This would mean an equivalence relation $M \times S$ where $(m, s) \sim (n, t)$ when $tm = sn$.

Yes, it applies as you say. In fact, right after this equivalence construction is carried out, it is usually abandoned and the elements are written like fractions $a/b$ instead of $(a,b)$.

---

For the latter questions, an example might help. Take $A = \Bbb Z$, then $K = \Bbb Q$. Let $L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$, then take e.g. $M = \Bbb Z \sqrt{2} + \Bbb Z \sqrt{3} \subset L$ and $S = \{1, 5, 5^2, \ldots\} \subset A$. Then $S^{-1} A$ is $\left\{\dfrac{k}{5^n} | k, n\in \Bbb Z, n \ge 0\right\}$, and
$S^{-1} M$ would be $\left\{\dfrac{k\sqrt{2} + m \sqrt{3}}{5^n} | k, m, n\in \Bbb Z, n \ge 0\right\}$. You can check directly that these two are indeed Abelian groups, and $S^{-1} A$ is a ring.

$M$ is a $\Bbb Z$-module (free of rank 2). $M$ is not a $S^{-1}\Bbb Z$-module, since e.g. $(1/5) \cdot \sqrt{2} \not \in M$.

$S^{-1} M$ is indeed a module over $S^{-1} A$: since it is already known to be an Abelian group, what's left to check is that $(S^{-1} A) (S^{-1} M) \subset S^{-1} M$. If we take a proper subset instead of the whole $(S^{-1} A)$, the inclusion will of course continue to hold (so, a module over a ring is always a module over its subring).